Spanish conditional in hypothetical clauses followed by the Spanish present subjunctive
I have a doubt as to why verb takes simple future conjugation instead of subjunctive conjugation in conditional tense followed by subject change.
For e.g

Contrataremos al nuevo profesor mientras (que) tengamos presupuesto.
We will hire the new teacher as long as we have the budget.
Here it is subjunctive (tengamos) instead of tenemos (simple present) because que is present.
In this statement no subject change is taking place, and there is no expression of doubt/wish/hope/uncertainity also, why is verb taking subjunctive form then?

In another example,
2. Aunque me regales rosas no saldré contigo a cenar.
2. Even if you buy me roses I won't go out with you for dinner.
In this example why is it saldre instead of salga?
My question is why are we using subjunctive (tengamos) instead of tenemos in 1st example but not using subjunctive (salga) instead of saldre in 2nd example?
P.S I am very new to this.
Can someone please help.
Muchas Gracias!

In your first case there is some doubt about the budget (hence subjunctive).  In the second case there is no doubt (hence future). " I .. WILL .. NOT .. GO .. OUT .. WITH .. YOU  .. EVER".  But note that "regales" is subjunctive, and "contrataremos" is future.  As I am fuzzy on the concepts myself, I am only commenting and not posting an answer.

I don't think that the use of "mientras" is correct in your first sentence. As far as I know, it's not used in conditional sentences like that one.
Take into account that mientras is used to refer to a lapse of time, an interval. And the act of hiring someone is something punctual, it occurs in an instant not in an interval. You can check the definition for that particle here.
For me the following sounds more natural

Contrataremos un nuevo profesor para el nuevo curso si tenemos presupuesto
or
Mantendremos contratado al nuevo profesor mientras tengamos presupuesto

Contrataremos - We will hire - [One specific day, he will be hired if there is enough budget]
Mantendremos contratado - We will keep him in the payroll - [He will have an employment while we have budget enough for paying him]
To summarize: I wouldn't use subjunctive in your first sentence.

"Cuando mientras introduce un verbo en subjuntivo, adquiere a menudo un matiz condicional: «La polémica no se extinguirá mientras persista la palabra escrita» (Liendo Platos [Ven. 1985])." (1. 1.1. b) https://www.rae.es/dpd/mientras)

Contrataremos al nuevo profesor mientras tengamos presupuesto.


If the verb after “mientras”  is in the present subjunctive, "mientras" is often translated: "as long as"."
Example:
"Mientras estés cansado, no tienes que trabajar."
(As long as you’re tired, you don’t have to work.)
If “mientras” is followed by the indicative and not the subjunctive, it often means “while” and describes two events that happen simultaneously, for example:
"Voy a cenar mientras tú ves la tele."
(I’m going to have dinner while you watch TV.)
"Mientras escucho música, hago la tarea."
(While I listen to music, I do the homework.)
Similarly,  “Aunque” conveys the meaning of “although” if followed by the indicative, for example:
"Aunque no quiero comer, iré al café contigo."
(Although I don’t want to eat, I will go to the café with you.)
On the other hand, “aunque” conveys the meaning of “even if” when followed by the subjunctive, for example:
"Aunque no quiera comer, iré al café contigo."
(Even if I don’t want to eat, I will go to the café with you.)
But either way, the verb in question is the verb following "aunque" (and not the verb in the following phrase).
